# Reactjs UseState & UseEffect Messing

Tags: reactjs

Below is a code i am using to set state for some data:

```
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);

const [trendData, setTrend] = useState([]);

const [thisMonthData, setThisMonth] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    graphData();
}, [loader]);

async function graphData() {

   
    await getRequest(process.env.REACT_APP_apiUrl + ':0000/abc/xyz').then( (response) => {

        let series = [];
        let months;


        for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {

             months = response[index]['Month'].split(',');

            series.push(response[index]['Useres'].split(',')); 


        } 

        setTrendMonth(series);
        setThisMonthData(series);
        console.log(thisMonthData);
        
        setLoader(false);
    });

}
```

And now i am attaching a response getting in `console.log(thisMonthData);` this. I have tried everything, including `thisMonthData` in `useEffect` and other state keys. But everytime data is going blank or missing values.

Whats wrong here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6YA9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIeIM.png)

Comment: Port :0000 ? ? ?

Comment: react is asynchronous. you wont get sth in `console.log` there. try `console.log(series)` and see if you get a result

Comment: series data is also changing and removing data from series variable if i am logging out of for loop. But if i am removing setTrend and setThismonth, then series log is workg fine.

Comment: @zipzit its just for example. Else port is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `await` and `then`, also try to log `thisMonthData` when they are changed with a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  graphData();
}, [loader]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(thisMonthData);
}, [thisMonthData]);

async function graphData() {
  try {
    const response = await getRequest(
      process.env.REACT_APP_apiUrl + ':0000/abc/xyz'
    );
    let series = [];
    let months;

    for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
      months = response[index]['Month'].split(',');
      series.push(response[index]['Useres'].split(','));
    }

    setTrendMonth(series);
    setThisMonthData(series);

    setLoader(false);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hi Sandeep Singh,*

Does the function getRequest() use axios or already does the  .json() in some step? Like in the ex:

```
fetch(myRequest)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {/***/}
```